# Custom styled MessageBox in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml, messagebox

I would like to ask if there is way how to create cusotm styled Messagebox in silverlight, with exactly same behavior as classic Messagebox class. Plus how to implement with MVVM pattern. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of custom messageboxes, just search in google. Here are some of them:

- [Custom MessageBox Control for Silverlight 3](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/CustomMessageBox.aspx)
- [Custom Silverlight Controls: Creating a reusable MessageBox dialog.](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/theonewith/archive/2008/08/06/custom-silverlight-controls-creating-a-reusable-messagebox-dialog-part-i.aspx)
- [Silverlight Modal Dialog With Custom User Controls](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/a01af6c8-c067-4fdd-bc01-d47cf3410feb/silverlight-modal-dialog.aspx)

All of them are with source code.