# How to change button text from OK/CANCEL to YES/NO for MessageBox in SL4?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

SL 4 provides a dialog box by MessageBox, but MessageBoxButton only provide option for button as OK, Cancel.  How to change it to YES, NO button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This MessageBox built into silverlight can't be changed beyond the capabilities that are exposed.

Your only solution would be to make a custom ChildWindow class which provides the functionality you want.  There are [many](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42477/Custom-MessageBox-Control-for-Silverlight-3) [examples](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/theonewith/archive/2008/08/06/custom-silverlight-controls-creating-a-reusable-messagebox-dialog-part-i.aspx) of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458282/custom-styled-messagebox-in-silverlight).

This has the advantage of acting more like other silverlight popup windows, and can be themed and skinned however you'd like, with whatever buttons and functionality you chose to implement.

This has the disadvantage that you are forced then to use a callback model rather than an a more usual imperative flow control.

Comment: Thanks. I only want to change text to YES/NO, no need to make a fancy style change. I am looking for a simple solution. Those solution is too complicated to me.

Comment: @KentZhou See the first part of my answer.  You can't change the text of the MessageBox, that capability isn't provided.  Your only choice is to do something more complicated.  You might find a 3rd party library that you could just download and use instead, but it still requires a change to a callback/event based control flow.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the `System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup`

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Button x:Name="showPopup"  Click="showPopup_Click" Height="100" Width="100" Content="Show Popup"/>
    <Popup x:Name="myPopup" IsOpen="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
        <Canvas  Height="200" Width="300" Background="Azure">
            <Button x:Name="closePopup" Click="closePopup_Click" Height="50" Width="100" Content="Close Popup"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Popup>
    <Canvas x:Name="myCanvas" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="Black"  Opacity=".4"></Canvas>
</Grid>

public partial class Page : UserControl
    {
        public Page()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void closePopup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            myPopup.IsOpen = false;
            myCanvas.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        private void showPopup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            myPopup.IsOpen = true;
            myCanvas.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
```

If you don't want to create your own popup, there probably are 3rd party messageboxes, but with this solution, you have eveything in your own hands.